# How to import my views from user in my urls.py file

Tags: django, url, django-urls, django-users

I am using Pycharm for my Django Project. It says that it is a unresolved reference.

[image]

In Startup/urls.py I have following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('vereinsapp/', include('vereinsapp.urls')),
    path('', include('vereinsapp.urls')),
    #Users
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('delete_user/', user_views.deleteuser, name='delete_user'),
    path('profile_confirm_delete/', user_views.profile_confirm_delete, name='profile_confirm_delete'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I also tried startup.users but then I get the error Message "no module named..":
[image]

Comment: If your project is working fine with import from users import views, then you should mark startup directory as sources root in PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

```
from users import views as user_views
from users.user_views import *
```

you have imported views but forgot to import functions inside views i think it should work